# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString not calling javascript function

Tags: objective-c, iphone, webview

I am working on a phone gap iOS application. I need to pass the APNs token received in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to my java script function.

`didRegisterFoRmoteNotification` is as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0)
 {
     NSString* token = [[[[deviceToken description]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""] ;
     NSLog(@"Device_Token     -----> %@\n",token);

    [self.viewController.webView loadHTMLString:@"<script type=text/javascript src=js/test.js></script>" baseURL:nil];
    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunc('skdjch')"];
}
```

and javascript function is:

```
function myFunc(str){
 alert(str)
};
```

but, `myFunc` is not getting called.
If I call `myFunc` from some other java script file then it works properly and displays he alert.
can anyone explain me what is wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Hey praneti patidar you can't invoke like `function myFunc(str){
 alert(str)
};` 
hope you are new to Phone gap u need bridge(Plugin) to pass the values from native iOS to your Phongap Javascript function

Your js should be like this

```
        `function onDeviceReady() {
           cordova.exec(function(winParam) {
                        if(winParam[2]=="8.0")
                        {

                        $rootScope.ios7subheadermargin="0%"
                        $rootScope.infotop="-13px"
                        $rootScope.infoleft="13%"
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        $rootScope.ios7subheadermargin="1%"
                        $rootScope.infotop="-16px"
                        $rootScope.infoleft="15%"
                        }
                        }, function(error) {
                        //alert(error)
                        }, "Pdfconverter","get_location",["",true]);

           }`
```

Here Pdfconverter is native iOS class(plugin) where get_location is the method and which is to be like this

```
 -(void)get_location:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    cmds = command;
    NSLog(@"The string is:%@",[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]);

    CDVPluginResult *result;
    NSString *str_lattitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kUserlattitude];
    NSString *str_longitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kUserlongitude];
    NSString *str_Osversion=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kUserVersion];
    NSArray *arr_values=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:str_lattitude,str_longitude,str_Osversion, nil];

    result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsArray:arr_values];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:cmds.callbackId];

}
```

on the above same i am sending my lattitude,longitude and OS version as array and in your case you will be sending device token...

Here above winParam holds the array values...

Hope this helps...:)

Comment: Hello Sudhan, yes I am new to phonegap so struggling with it hard :). I think that the example you have given is calling a native iOS function from javascript, but i nee to call a javascript function from native code to stop the device token.

Comment: praneti i just replied for the method to pass the token to your javascript function(phonegap application),secondly are you asking to show alert on webview that you placed on viewcontroller? for this use NSNotificationCenter so that delegate make post observer which can be listened on viewcontroller ....